# How to move along the intersection of two surfaces

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, parametric, curves, intersection-theory

I'll use a concrete example to illustrate what I want to do.  Let's say I have the surfaces $Z = x^2 + y^2$ and $Z = 1$.  Assume that I start at point $(1,0,1)$, which I know is in the intersection of the two surfaces.  I eventually want to end up at a point that I also know is on the intersection.  Again, for concreteness, let's just say I want to go to $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1)$.

I know that for this particular example I need to move along the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.  However, I'm just using it as an example for which I know the solution.  Let's assume that I am unable to find an explicit formula for the intersection between my two surfaces.  How do I choose a curve that moves from the start point to the end point that is guaranteed to always be on the intersection?

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that your question is "How do I parameterize the intersection of two generic surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$"?

Comment: Almost, but it will eventually be extended to arbitrary dimensions.  Also, I'd also be OK with a method to prove that, for a particular set of hypersurfaces, no such parameterization exists.  A proof that the problem is algebraically unsolvable would be valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume we are in dimension 3.
If the intersection is regular then you may use an ode to bring you around. Now, where to finish your path depends on how you specify the points.
But say that the curve is the intersection of $f(z,y,z)=0$ and $g(x,y,z)=0$
and that you start at $\xi_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. Then $f$ and $g$ are constant along a curve $\xi_t=(x_t,y_t,z_t)$ passing through that point, whence $\nabla f \cdot \dot{\xi}=\nabla g \cdot \dot{\xi}=0$. When gradients are independent vectors (so the intersection is regular) then 
$$ \dot{\xi} = C(t) \ \nabla f(\xi)\times \nabla g(\xi), \ \ \xi(0)=\xi_0$$
where the  constant $C(t)$ in principle may be chosen at your convenience (also negative). Solving this ode gives you a path.

Comment: This is great to start with, thanks.  Now, my particular application is in arbitrary dimensions but involves the intersection of hyperplanes and hyperspheres only, so I hope that my intersection is nice enough.  I'd like to know which branch of math I should be looking at so I can understand how to generalize your solution?

Comment: I don't know about references for this. In general in dimension $d$  if you have constraints $f_1=...=f_k=0$ ($k<d$) then you should use a vector in the kernel of the $k\times d$ matrix $[\nabla f_1 \  ... \ \nabla f_k]^T$. In dimension 3 this happens to be expressible in terms of the cross product. Also if $k\leq d-2$ then the kernel is of more than 1 dimension which gives you some freedom in the way you move around (which is not really present, except for choice of the direction, in our example above).

Comment: That's very useful, thank you.  I don't need a reference, just a term to start googling :-)  Would this just be algebraic geometry, or is there a particular field?

Comment: Perhaps "moving along a constraint" ? (but haven't tried). The problem is perhaps not too far away from dynamical systems (my domain), but again even though the problem seems natural to me I haven't come across it in this form before.

Comment: Interesting.  Well then, is it sufficient to say the following: let $\vec{v} \in ker(M)$, where $M$ is the $k \times d$ matrix you described.  I may choose $\vec{v}$ arbitrarily.  Then $\dot{\xi} = C(t)\vec{v}, \xi(0) = \xi_0$?  Or are there additional constraints on the choice of $\vec{v}$?

Comment: In principle that is fine. Better make your choice relatively smooth perhaps. But you may encouter a couple of problems, notably points where the rank of M fails to be maximal. In our first example, if $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ fails to be independent you will get stuck at some point (even though that point is not really a singularity). Another thing which I have used in programming is that you after a while will run slightly off the constraints (from numerical errors), you may then use a small negative dissipative term times the gradients to bring you back.

Comment: I seem to be missing something.  From the above two equations, the gradients are: $\triangledown f = (-2x, -2y,1)$ and $\triangledown  g = (0,0,1)$.  Their cross product is $\vec{v} = (-2y, -2x, 0)$.  When that is integrated the solution is an exponential that grows without bound, rather than a circle.  Did I miss something?

Comment: Just a bad calculation. The cross product is $\pm (-2y,2x,0)$ which gives a circle.

Comment: Oh wow, oops.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is some kind of algorithm to do this, because the intersection may be not connected, even for smooth surfaces.

For example, the intersection of the surfaces $Z=\sin x+\cos y$ and $Z=1$ is an infinite union of disjoint circles (well, sort of).

Comment: There was originally only one tag, "algebraic geometry", so perhaps OP wants to restrict to polynomials.

Comment: That's correct, yes